# Рассчитать оптимальное значение масштабирования при поиске по карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я решил написать свой компонент поиска по Яндекс-карте, чтобы можно было свободно изменять стили оформления. При вводе строки в инпут, компонент поиска делает запрос за подсказками, выводит их в разметку, а при клике по подсказке, делает еще один запрос в геокодер, получает координаты и переводит карту по указанным координатам.

Все работает довольно неплохо, но никак не получается получить оптимальный уровень зума для каждого результата, как это делается при нативном поиске (компонент searchControl). Я пробовал использовать вместо panTo метод setBounds, но для карты устанавливался слишком большой зум :(

Что нужно сделать для того, чтобы по координатам зум устанавливался правильно? Т.е. если ищется город -- то увеличение должно быть небольшим, если дом в городе -- то большим.

http://jsbin.com/biqihiq/29

Вот пример того, что я уже сделал. Все работает как надо, за исключением правильного масштабирования. Как этого добиться?

Спасибо!

Comment: Точно не помню. Но по клику результат в калбеке можно вытащить boundedBy ответа с API. Вот его можно попробовать использовать

Comment: спасибо! помогло

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря помощи Андрея ProjectSoft, удалось настроить правильное масштабирование с помощью обращения по координатам, приходящим в ответе геокодера через res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'). 
Пример на сайте апи карт:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode